# How to count the number of features that lead to each leaf in an rpart object?

Tags: r, rpart

Given an `rpart` object, I want to be able to extract how many features were used before arriving at each leaf. In other words, I want to know how many pieces of information were used in making a classification decision for each leaf.

For example, here is an `rpart` object applied to the `titanic` dataset:

```
library(titanic)
library(rpart)

titanic.rpart <- rpart::rpart(survived ~., data = titanic)

titanic.rpart$frame[,1:2]
```

Here is the critical information from the `frame`:

var    n

1  sex 2201

2  age 1731

4  LEAF 1667

5   class   64

10 LEAF   48

11 LEAF   16

3   class  470

6  LEAF  196

7  LEAF  274

From the `frame` attribute, I can access the structure of the decision tree including the number of cases that reached each node / leaf. However, what I really want to know is, for each leaf, how many nodes occurred prior to that leaf? This will tell me how many pieces of information were looked up for each case when it is classified.

For example, looking at the titanic tree (see image below), it looks like the first leaf, occurring at a depth of 4, occurs after a `sex` and `age` node. Thus, this leaf required 2 pieces of information. As 1667 cases were classified at this leaf, this leaf used 1667 * 2 = 3334 pieces of information.

The next leaf at a depth of 10 occurred after a `sex`, `age`, and `class` nod. Thus, this leaf requires 3 pieces of information. As 48 cases were classified at this leaf, this leaf used 48 * 3 = 144 pieces of information.

Following this procedure for each leaf, I can calculate the total amount of information used as follows:

Total Info Used in tree = 1667 * 2 + 48 * 3 + 16 * 3 + 196 * 2 + 274 * 2 = 4466

I can then divide this by the total number of cases to get the average amount of information used per case as 4466 / 2201 = 2.03. In fact, this is really what I want in the end.

Here's the question: What code can I use to perform these calculations from an `rpart` object? Or to be more concrete, how can I determine, for each leaf, how many nodes occurred prior to that leaf?

[image]